# Embarrassed that I can't get fancybox working

Tags: javascript, fancybox-2

MVC 3 and fancybox 2.

Should be straight forward but somehow I have made a mess of things.

First since I am using this only on one page (cshtml) I add the scripts via:

```
Html.AddScriptParts(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"));
Html.AddCssFileParts(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5"));
```

When I look in the debugger I see jquery.fancybox.pzck.js loaded. When I inspect the element I do not see the jquery.fancybox.css styles applied...(css is default so maybe there aren't any to apply?)

My onready is:

```
$(function ()
{
   $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

and my link is:

```
<div id="ThreadLink">
   <a id="ForumFrameLink" href="https://www.google.com" class="fancybox">asdf</a>
</div>
```

It is acting as though my onready is not attaching...in other words it just follows the link to Google.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: Maybe try to create a JSfiddle and see if you can reproduce the issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSFiddle link you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/ramjet/54kag/

Use the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ThreadLink a").fancybox({
        type: "iframe"
    });
});
```

And then your HTML simply becomes:

```
<div id="ThreadLink">
    <a id="ForumFrameLink" href="http://www.foxnews.com">asdf</a>
</div>
```

It seems that `type: "iframe"` needed to be set. After glancing over the documentation, it looks like you can also just set the class of the `a` to `iframe` instead to get the same functionality.

"Corrected" fiddle for your viewing pleasure: http://jsfiddle.net/54kag/1/

Comment: If you want to create a JS fiddle I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Well, you're linking to a web site rather than an actual image. If you link to a picture , the lightbox works as intended.

Comment: Is this the functionality you're after?

Comment: Ah, I see. You're trying to do an iframe.

Comment: Yes an iFrame..so as I reading through the site I have to chnage my  $(".fancybox").fancybox(); function with more parms right...?

Comment: OK and there in lies my misunderstanding. I thought jquery would traverse everything till it found the FIRST class fancybox. But instead I have to trigger off the div then jump to the a...?

Comment: It is a good question, and I did not need to change the selector. Here is another fiddle which should make it less confusing for you: http://jsfiddle.net/54kag/2/

Comment: SO would it be safe to say 6 one half doz the other...rather than detail it out in the onload handler you can apply additional classes that have it detailed out.

Comment: The issue lies in the fact that you need to "tell" fancybox that the element is supposed to open up a web site in a `iframe`.

Comment: @user1278561 Yes, you can apply the class `fancybox.iframe` to each Fancybox element that you want to have that behavior.